# Serve static website along side Django App [DRF API] on same subdomain?

Tags: django, nginx, webserver

I have a subdomain as : app.example.com

Now I want to serve a static website on app.example.com which does some API based querying on the Django app which I want to host on same base URL something like : app.example.com/app/api....

But I am unable to do so. My Nginx configuration is as follows :

```
server {


    root /home/ubuntu/dist/;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name app.example.com;

        location / {
        alias /home/ubuntu/dist/ ;
        try_files $uri /$uri index.html last;
                 }

    location /admind {
        alias /home/ubuntu/admind/dist/ ;
        try_files $uri /$uri/ index.html last;

    }
        location /app/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {
    if ($host = app.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name app.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Whenever I implement the following configuration app.example.com opens as expected but the Django app url app.example.com/app/api or for that matter /app/admin/ of Django Admin doesn't open up and throws 404. 
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you just append a `BASE_URL` to all the core `url_patterns`, something like,

`settings.py`

```py
BASE_URl = 'app/'
```

`urls.py`

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
  path("%sadmin/" % settings.BASE_URL, AdminView, name='admin'),
  path("%sapi/" % settings.BASE_URL, MyAPIView, name="myapi"),
]
```

This way all your URLs already start with app/, so even if you reverse proxy the root `app.example.com` it'll still serve on `app/`

Comment: Thanks Ayush. This seems to be working. :) I have tweaked my urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a header to tell Django you are serving from a sub-path.

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME app;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
}
```

Comment: The alternative is to put `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/app'` in your settings.py.

Comment: Now it's redirect me to <base_url>/app/app/admin which again says 404 not found.